# Ibm j9 java.util.Executors ClassNotFound

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, j9

I am developing an application using IBM j9 JDK. When I try to use the following line of code:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

I get a runtime exception saying NoClassDefFoundError for java.util.Executors

Is there a different way I can open a concurrent thread using ibm j9?

Comment: Are you sure that's not a very old version?

Comment: It is a very old version. Is there another way to open a concurrent thread using an old version of the jre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are running a pre-1.5 java version, so you'll need to adapt, perhaps with [pre-1.5 util.concurrent library](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/intro.html) which has a [QueuesExecutor](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/QueuedExecutor.html).

Without library you could use a `Thread` and implement a thread-safe queue yourself.